# Convert Instream to String Faster (Android)?

Tags: java, javascript, android

How do I convert an Instream to a string fast right now im using..

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But this takes atleast 2-3 minutes on the emulator. I found out it would be faster if I converted the instream to a Byte Array then to a String?. Does anybody have any knowledge of this?

Comment: @Philip 
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead.

Comment: Would this work
          response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
 
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                // Connection was established. Get the content. 
              ByteArrayOutputStream i = (ByteArrayOutputStream) response.getEntity();